# Ajax url cambia en el servidor - MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc

¿Está mal declarar urls en ajax de esta forma?

```
$.ajax
        ({
            url: '/SFI_IncentivoDet/buscarIncentivosSinDetalles',
            type: 'post'
        });
```

Estoy trabajando con las funciones en archivos separados, en algunos casos tengo que poner ../ antes del controlador (aparentemente si llamo a la función desde una vista diferente al controlador de destino)

El problema es que cuando paso la aplicación al servidor o a otra computadora tengo que modificar el parámetro url en algunos casos.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Utilizas algún framework o simplemente jQuery en el HTML? Lo comento porque algunos traen utilidades para evitar esto con las rutas.

Comment: No uso nada mas que MVC y JQuery para eso, desde la vista llamo a la funcion de Jquery y ahi Ajax que va a la accion del controlador

Comment: Podrías probar a utilizar window.location.pathname + tu URL (pese a que igual tienes que poner los ../ si es necesario), así evitarás tener que cambiar la URL en algunos casos.

Comment: Voy a probar esto tambien, muchas gracias :)

Comment: La respuesta de miguel es exactamente lo que te quería comentar. De nada!

Answer (score 3):

Si estás usando ASP MVC sería conveniente que generases los enlaces mediante el `@Url.Action`. Al cual con pasarle el controlador y el método que quieres llamar,  este te generá las direcciones dinamicamente. Consiguiendo con esto que no tengas que cambiar las `URL` manualmente cada vez que cambias de servidor.

```
$.ajax
({
    url: '@Url.Action("SFI_IncentivoDet","buscarIncentivosSinDetalles")',
    type: 'post'
});
```

Comment: Voy a probar eso, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Si pongo esto no entra a la función directamente, deberia andar?